# Javascript: can constructors process an array from a string, then store in the same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor

I am learning programming from scratch and am using it for a real-life task through javascript. I wanted to use object constructors to reduce repeating code. What i need help in is to use the non commented part of my code to work like what is commented. I use the getElementById in html to see my results since i will be using a webpage to perform the task. I think that the array, "storesArray" is the problem, but not sure. I will be creating many objects of the same nature, and wanted to use a constructor to convert the string value of a property in the object, into an array, then store it as the value for an array property in the same object. Not quite sure what i'm doing wrong. Any help will be gladly welcome. Much Thanks

```
<body>
<p id="display1"><p/> 
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function page(name, storesArray, storeNumS) { 
    this.name = name;                               
    this.storesArray = [];                         
    this.storeNumS = storeNumS;                    
    this.chgToArray = function(this.storeNumS){ 
        this.storesArray = this.storeNumS.split(" ");
        return;
    };
}

var _001_01 = new page("_001_01", [], "01 03 05 56 87 06 07");
document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = _001_01.storesArray;

/* //Code below shows result i'd like. Code above is a constuctor version of below
var _001_01 = {
  name: "xyz_001_01", 
  storesArray: [],
  chgToArray: function(storeNumS){              
    _001_01.storesArray = storeNumS.split(" "); 
    }
};

_001_01.chgToArray("01 03 05 56 87 06 07");
document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = _001_01.storesArray;
*/
</script>
</html>
```

Update: March17.2016

I didn't know I didn't need a separate array variable to turn that string of numbers into an array. Thanks for that shortcut Bobby. Perhaps a little explanation might suffice my reason Alex/ O'Mara. My main goal was to rearrange data. Instead of a list of STORES associated with every unique PAGE advert, i'd prefer the list of all PAGEs for every unique STORE. After turning the pages into objects that kept an array of stores, i used a nested loop that scans through an array of the page objects, then in each object, scan through the array of stores. If the store object found a match in a page object's store array, that page name will be pushed into an array of the stores object being searhed for.

Let me know if i've lost you. But the reason that i made a separate array was i  didn't know if the local variable would vanish if i didn't pass it to a property of the object so that it could be searched though later by a seperate function. Not sure how i can show my code, this question thing doesn't work like a forum thread does it

But i am using the innerHTML line as a debugging feature since i'd like to display the results in a web page when i make this app/thingy. I am also creating this little tool for a friend of mine who isn't tech/code savvy since we both need it. 
I'm sure my code can be far more efficent, but i'll get there eventually. I'm learning heaps from you all. I really appreciate your comments and contributions.

Comment: Why is storesArray an argument if you have no intentions of using it? And instead generating the storesArray from the storeNumS? Also, your storeNumS aren't displaying in the storesArray, because you are not calling `this.chgToArray` anywhere.

Comment: `function(this.storeNumS){` is not valid, what are you trying to do there?

Comment: "*I wanted to use object constructors to reduce repeating code.*" - Don't. Use constructors only if you need to construct objects. Use normal functions to avoid repeating code. If the whole purpose of this thing is to create an array, just make a function that returns this array and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, I actually do need to create objects. And lots of them.

I just thought that if i wanted to pass info in through the creation of a new instance of an object, that i'd need to identify that the array property (argument - i guess) of that object is empty to begin with, but the interntal function (method) will fill it in later. Its the use of arrays IN the object-property that was difficult finding answers for. Objects in arrays and arrays of whatever else have plentiful documentation online. But since im learning by myself, it can get confusing at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not calling `chgToArray` anywhere, if you want to call this automatically, just set the `this.storesArray` property to the result of `storeNumS.split()`.

Also, I removed `storesArray` as an argument to the contructor, because you are not using it anywhere in the provided code, simply add it back in if you have plans to use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function page(name, storeNumS) {
    this.name = name;
    this.storeNumS = storeNumS;
    this.storesArray = storeNumS.split(" ")
}

var _001_01 = new page("_001_01", "01 03 05 56 87 06 07");
document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = _001_01.storesArray;

/* //Code below shows result i'd like. Code above is a constuctor version of below
var _001_01 = {
  name: "xyz_001_01",
  storesArray: [],
  chgToArray: function(storeNumS){
    _001_01.storesArray = storeNumS.split(" ");
    }
};

_001_01.chgToArray("01 03 05 56 87 06 07");
document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = _001_01.storesArray;
*/
</script>
```

Comment: I just updated my question post with a response below the code. Thanks for your help.